# Overwrite single line in txt file

Tags: c

I'm writing a C program that writes to a txt file. The first line is meant to be a number, that I want to update regularly. The problem I'm having is that it starts at 1, and when I reach the number 10, it overwrites the next character in the file.
This is what I'm getting:

Before:

```
9
hello
```

After:

```
10 
ello
```

I want this:

```
10
hello
```

How should I do this? Thanks in advance

PS: This is my code:

```
int nkv = 9;
char nkvst[10];
sprintf(nkvst, "%d\n", nkv);
fputs(nkvst, fp[3]);
fputs("hello", fp[3]);
fseek(fp[3], 0, SEEK_SET);
nkv = 10;
sprintf(nkvst, "%d\n", nkv);
fputs(nvkst, fp[3]);
```

Comment: show us your code .. its hard to debug without it

Comment: Updated. fp is declared as FILE *fp[]; as I want to create and edit multiple files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First solution would be avoiding rewriting in open file:

1. read and store data from whole file
2. change what you need
3. rewrite the whole file with new data

If you still wanted to mess around your file you could write your numbers with some `' '` spaces as a reserve:

```
sprintf(nkvst, "%11d\n", nkv);
```

If you had for example number -2147483648, it would take 11 characters. So there is 11 character padding set for you to be safe.

Comment: Thanks. I'd thought of that but was wondering if it would be inefficient to rewrite the whole file time and time again. I think I'll go with the blank spaces option, given that it probably isn't very "expensive" to allocate memory for blank spaces. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Simple solution: store your number in the file with extra digits/spaces (at your convenience) if you know by advance which is the greatest number you want to store in the file.

For example, if your number is not going to be higher than 999999, then:

```
int nkv = 9;
char nkvst[10];
sprintf(nkvst, "%.6d\n", nkv);
fputs(nkvst, fp[3]);
fputs("hello", fp[3]);
fseek(fp[3], 0, SEEK_SET);
nkv = 10;
sprintf(nkvst, "%.6d\n", nkv);
fputs(nvkst, fp[3]);
```